# C# dotnet test: What is the purpose of „Description“ attribute compared to a comment?

Tags: c#, .net-core, mstest, xunit, visual-studio-2022

***A Code example:***

```cs
[Fact]
[Description(„This is a test“)]
public void Test1() => Assert.Equal(1,1);
```

This example uses xUnit, but I also created one with MSTest.
I’m using dotnet 6.

**The question:**
Considering that the description attribute does not appear in the console output nor in any log files, what is it used for?
What is the difference between the description attribute and a comment (either `//` or `///`)?

**What I’ve tried so far:**
I already tried the following commands:

- `dotnet test`
- `dotnet test -l html`
- `dotnet test -l trx`
- `dotnet test -l „console;verbosity=normal“`
- `dotnet test -l „console;verbosity=detailed“`
- `dotnet test -t`

I also looked into the text explorer of Visual Studio 2022 and could not see anything related to the description attribute.

I expected that the description attribute would show up somewhere in the logs or in the test explorer.

Comment: When you mark Description and hit F12, what is the namespace of Description? In which package is it defined?

Comment: In my MSTest example: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`

Comment: In my xUnit example from above: `System.ComponentModel`

Comment: Most likely its useful for reflection. Important to note that `DescriptionAttribute` is part of the `System.ComponentModel` namespace, while comments are thrown out by the compiler altogether and therefore cannot be exposed to the code itself for use by reflection. The `///` documentation comments don't get picked up by code or the compiler either, rather at the *IDE* level, they will be picked up and displayed for our programming convenience. Point in case a Description attribute can be pulled into code as a `DescriptionAttribute` **object**, and you can do things with it after

Answer (score 2):

The description is to provide the description of the test which is useful while reviewing the test. The description is processed by the test runner and comments are in general ignored by the compiler.

So Description is used to provide information about your test that will be displayed by the test and will be used by the test runner. while comments are for humans like us (programmers) for reading the code.

Comment: Could you further elaborate on where the information about my tests is displayed when using the Description attribute?

Comment: @ShadowDragon: I don't know where this information is actually displayed. To be honest, I'm not sure if *anything* uses it.